# Replace text in Google Sheet hyperlink using Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I'm not much of a coder, but I've used some bits I've found on this site and others to put together a small Google Script for organizing files into a Google sheet. Basically it pulls the file names and links from a specified Drive folder, and prints these along with the respective hyperlinks into a Google Sheet, and the script works perfectly for that. I want to remove part of the file name from the hyperlink though and can't quite figure it out. Here's what the script pulls so far, and what I want the edited hyperlink to show:

| File ID | File Link | Hyperlink | Edited Hyperlink |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Adam Smith - Document 2023-1 | https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mh82jf89j23/view?uspdrivesdk | =hyperlink("https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mh82jf89j23/view?uspdrivesdk", "Adam Smith - Document 2023-1") | =hyperlink("https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mh82jf89j23/view?uspdrivesdk", "2023-1") |
| John Maynard - Document 2023-1 | https://drive.google.com/file/d/ijeficoq38vc8/view?uspdrivesdk | =hyperlink("https://drive.google.com/file/d/ijeficoq38vc8/view?uspdrivesdk", "John Maynard - Document 2023-1") | =hyperlink("https://drive.google.com/file/d/ijeficoq38vc8/view?uspdrivesdk", "2023-1") |

I know how to use regexreplace and substitute as a Google Sheets formula, but it doesn't work on hyperlinks, and I don't know how to incorporate either into the script, which is below:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var c1 = s.getRange("C1")
  var c2 = s.getRange("B1");
  var c3 = s.getRange("A1")
  var fldr = DriveApp.getFolderById("1Kt43CdFyWBFrx1Wo4eJMLf0UB0RTPYiS");
  var files = fldr.getFiles();
  var urls = [], names = [], ids = [], f, hyp, str;
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    f = files.next();
    hyp = f.getUrl();
    str = '=hyperlink("' + f.getUrl() + '", "'+ f.getName() + '")';
    urls.push([str]);
    names.push([f.getUrl()]);
    ids.push([f.getName().replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "")]); //Remove filename extensions
    //ids.push([f.getName()]); //Filename with extensions
  }

  s.getRange(c1.getRow(), c1.getColumn(), urls.length).setFormulas(urls);
  s.getRange(c2.getRow(), c2.getColumn(), names.length).setValues(names);
  s.getRange(c3.getRow(), c3.getColumn(), ids.length).setValues(ids);


}
```

Would appreciate any help with this - thanks!

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Is your table your expected situation? If my understanding is correct, can you provide the sample input situation? First, I would like to correctly understand your question. I apologize for this.

Comment: What do you want the rule to be for editing the hyperlink? Last six characters? After the last space? You could also use the Formula function to analyze the hyperlink text and strip out parts of from there

Comment: @pgSystemTester I wouldn't want to do last six or etc characters as the number of characters in the document varies, but I'd want it to be everything after the last space yes. I'm not familiar with that forumula function, but I don't want to use a formula in the google sheet to accomplish this, I'd prefer everything to be contained in the script so I can run it and have the desired names set from there.

Comment: @Tanaike no problem — the table is my expected solution except for the Hyperlink column. I'm currently getting the Hyperlink column results, but I want to get the Edited Hyperlink column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your reply, how about modifying your script as follows?

#### Modification points:

- In order to retrieve your expected value, I used `split`.
- In your script, `setFormulas` and `setValues` are used. I thought that in your situation, only `setValues` can be used.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var fldr = DriveApp.getFolderById("1Kt43CdFyWBFrx1Wo4eJMLf0UB0RTPYiS");
  var files = fldr.getFiles();
  var values = [];
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    f = files.next();
    var hyp = f.getUrl();
    var name = f.getName().replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "");
    var str = '=hyperlink("' + hyp + '", "' + name.split(" ").pop() + '")';
    values.push([name, hyp, str]);
  }
  s.getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

- When this script is run, the value of `2023-1` is retrieved from `Adam Smith - Document 2023-1`.

Comment: Clever usage of `pop`, I didn't know that would RETURN the last value.

Comment: @pgSystemTester Thank you for your comment. When the last element is retrieved from an array, for example, `array[array.length - 1]` can be also used. In this case, it is required to declare `array`. In OP's situation, I thought that it is not required to declare the result of `split` as `array`. So, in this case, I used `pop`.

Comment: Yep, I would have used the `length` so thanks for the info (as always!)

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong the accepted answer ([Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike) always crushes it), however the question incorrectly asserts that a sheets formula could not be leveraged ("*doesn't work on hyperlinks*").

By putting the below formula cell `C1` the sheet will spill the values and there would be no need for the script to do anything in column `C`.

```
=fILTER(HYPERLINK(B1:B,SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A," ",REPT("☺",999)),999),"☺","")),A1:A<>"")
```